# How to remove appended items from DropDownlist on postback in ASP.NET and C#

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, postback, cascade

I have two `DropDownList` controls in cascade (the second one is populated based on the selection made on the first one):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProduct" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
    AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="ddlProduct_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Value="" Selected="True"> - Product - </asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategory" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCategory_SelectedIndexChanged" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Value="" Selected="True"> - Category - </asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

In the `ddlProduct.SelectedIndexChanged` event handler I have the following code:

```
ddlCategory.DataSource = _productService.GetCategoryByProductId(ddlProduct.SelectedValue);
ddlCategory.DataTextField = "CategoryName";
ddlCategory.DataValueField = "CategoryId";
ddlCategory.DataBind();
```

The first time a user choose a Product from `ddlProduct` the `ddlCategory` is populated correctly. The following times, the Categories in `ddlCategory` are appended to those that were selected the first time and so on. I tried to put in `ddlProduct.SelectedIndexChanged`:

```
ddlCategory.Items.Clear();
```

but the method removes also the hardcoded item

```
<asp:ListItem Value="" Selected="True"> - Category - </asp:ListItem>
```

How can I just delete the appended item from ddlCategory?

Comment: so you want to keep this `<asp:ListItem Value="" Selected="True"> - Category - </asp:ListItem>
` listItem after  `ddlProduct.SelectedIndexChanged` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set `AppendDataboundItems="false"` and insert the default item manually, for example in [`DropDownList.DataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.databound) event:

```
protected void ddlCategory_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlCategory.Items.Count > 0)
    {
            ddlCategory.Items.Insert(0, " - Category - ");
            ddlCategory.Items[0].Value = "";
            ddlCategory.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `AppendDataBoundItems="true"` and append empty item manually after `DataBind` method call

Answer (score 1):

After removing category items you can add default category using code...

```
ddlCategory.Items.Add(new ListItem("- Category -", "0", true));
```